# Trying to find the CFC that defines this component

Tags: coldfusion

Ok, I am new to Coldfusion components, though I think I understand them in concept.  I have taken over a project and in the data access model, all I have is a cfm that has this line in it:

```
<!--- Invoke data service --->
<cfset Variables.namedService =     createObject("component","services.namedService").init(datasource='dsname') />
```

I need to modify the sql behind this component, but can't figure out where to go look for it based on this createObject.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the page with debugging enabled.  Look at the query in question.  You should see something like this:

`getDate (Datasource=dw, Time=15ms, Records=1) in D:\xx\xxx\CustomTags\Components\OR\CaseAndProceduresDan.cfc @ 13:31:04.004`

```
sql for the getDate query
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction.  I found the path to the CFC; however, it is further up the directory tree than I have access to.  So now i know where it is, I just can't get to it.

Comment: Dan - good tip... never try to develop without debugging anyway - one of the strengths of the platform.

Answer (score 4):

Look for a *folder* called "services" containing a *file* called "namedService.cfc". If you can't find the folder you might look for a mapping called "services" - mappings may be found in the Application.cfc (look for a line containing /Services) or in the CF admin.

In the end though - searching for NamedService.cfc will likely turn something up and make things clearer.

Comment: The docs for this are here: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/building-blocks-of-coldfusion-applications/building-and-using-coldfusion-components/using-coldfusion-components-developing-guide.html (scroll down to the bottom: "Specifying the CFC location")

Comment: Went through and found nothing in the directory structure and there is no Application.cfc for this app.  I also don't have access to the CF Admin.

Comment: Well you are obviously not working on a local copy of the code :/ - that might be something you should get your project folks to address for you. Can't get much done with such handicaps.